# filtering data with array of objects data es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, filter

I am trying to filter array of objects with another array of objects.

```
var actualData = [{modifiedy: "USER", createdOn: "2021-03-18", id: 33 },{modifiedy: "USER", createdOn:"2021-03-18", id: 22},{modifiedy: "USER", createdOn: "2021-03-18", id: 36},  {modifiedy: "USER", createdOn: "2021-03-18", id: 11 }] 

var selectedItems = [33,22]
```

I need to return Items which are not include in actual Data.

I have tried using below function but I am getting undefined "some" error.

```
 const filtered = result.filter((p) => !p.checkedItems.some((a) => checkedItems.includes(a.id)));
```

I have searched a lot achieve my requirement but I didn't any solution can some one help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Please post valid code representations of your data. What you have copied from dev tools console is not a useable structure to run your code with. Also both `p.checkItems` and `checkedItems` seem to be undefined. See [mre]

Comment: @charlietfl I have updated my question can you check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 var filtered = actualData.filter(function (item) {
        return selectedItems.indexOf(item.id) === -1;
    });
    console.log('filtered', filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you need to find items in *selectedItems* which are not in *actualData*, right? So if you have

```
var selectedItems = [33,22,9];
```

And actualData provided in your example, you result to be

```
Array [ 9 ]
```

Right? In this case you should do something like this:

```
const filtered = selectedItems.filter(item => !actualData.find(data => data.id === item));
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter()` and **ES6**

```js
const actualData = [
  { modifiedy: "USER", createdOn: "2021-03-18", id: 33 },
  { modifiedy: "USER", createdOn: "2021-03-18", id: 22 },
  { modifiedy: "USER", createdOn: "2021-03-18", id: 36 },
  { modifiedy: "USER", createdOn: "2021-03-18", id: 11 },
];

const selectedItems = [33, 22];

const notIncludedData = actualData.filter((a, i) => selectedItems.indexOf(a.id) !== i);

console.log(notIncludedData);
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashok Kumar but accepted answer already worked for me.